# RANK OVER() WINDOW FUNCTION - Snowflake SQL

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, window-functions

How to write a window function "Rank() over"  for the following requirement:
GET THE LATEST MOD_DATE (20221104) and GROUP the output records BY columns A, B, C, and AMT1 from the INPUT TABLE - then sum up the AMT2 FOR EACH GROUPING).  Please refer to the image below.

[image]

I tried the following but it does not work

```
 SELECT A,B,C, AMT1,AMT2  FROM   
     (SELECT A, B, C, MOD_DATE, AMT1, AMT2  
      RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY A, B, C  ORDER BY LAST_MODIFIED_DATE DESC) AS rk     
      FROM INPUT_TABLE) 
 WHERE rk = 1;
```

Appreciate your inputs!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To choose the latest record per group the RANK and QUALIFY could be used:

```
SELECT A, B, C, MOD_DATE, AMT1, AMT2   
FROM INPUT_TABLE
QUALIFY RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY A, B, C ORDER BY LAST_MODIFIED_DATE DESC) = 1;
```

---

Getting total:

```
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT A, B, C, MOD_DATE, AMT1, AMT2   
   FROM INPUT_TABLE
   QUALIFY RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY A, B, C ORDER BY LAST_MODIFIED_DATE DESC) = 1
)
SELECT A, B, C, MOD_DATE, SUM(AMT1) AS AMT1_TOTAL, SUM(AMT2) AS AMT2_SUM
FROM cte
GROUP BY A, B, C, MOD_DATE
```

Alternatively using only windowed functions:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A, B, C, MOD_DATE, 
    SUM(AMT1) OVER(PARTITION BY A, B, C LAST_MODIFIED_DATE) AS AMT1_TOTAL
    SUM(AMT2) OVER(PARTITION BY A, B, C LAST_MODIFIED_DATE) AS AMT2_TOTAL
FROM INPUT_TABLE
QUALIFY RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY A, B, C ORDER BY LAST_MODIFIED_DATE DESC) = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

So if we type out your data by hand:

```
with INPUT_TABLE(A, B,C, MOD_DATE, AMT1, AMT2) as (
    select * from values
        ('ABC','DEF','GHI',20221102, 2.00, 10.00),
        ('ABC','DEF','GHI',20221104, 2.00, 15.00),
        ('ABC','DEF','GHI',20221104, 2.00, 20.00),
        ('ABC','DEF','GHI',20221102, 3.00, 10.00),
        ('ABC','DEF','GHI',20221104, 3.00, 10.00),
        ('ABC','DEF','GHI',20221104, 3.00, 20.00),
        ('ABC','DEF','GHI',20221104, 4.00, 5.00),
        ('ABC','DEF','GHI',20221104, 4.00, 10.00),
        ('ABC','DEF','GHI',20221102, 5.00, 5.00),
        ('ABC','DEF','GHI',20221104, 5.00, 5.00)
)
```

then look at you starting point SQL, `LAST_MODIFIED_DATE` does not exist, this is what you appear to be trying to find, so this SQL at a start should look more like:

```
SELECT A,B,C, AMT1,AMT2  FROM (
    SELECT A, B, C, MOD_DATE, AMT1, AMT2  
      ,RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY A, B, C, AMT1 ORDER BY MOD_DATE DESC) AS rk     
    FROM INPUT_TABLE
) 
WHERE rk = 1;
```

but this has "too many rows"

| A | B | C | AMT1 | AMT2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | DEF | GHI | 2 | 15 |
| ABC | DEF | GHI | 2 | 20 |
| ABC | DEF | GHI | 3 | 10 |
| ABC | DEF | GHI | 3 | 20 |
| ABC | DEF | GHI | 4 | 5 |
| ABC | DEF | GHI | 4 | 10 |
| ABC | DEF | GHI | 5 | 5 |

if we drop the rank filter:

```
   SELECT A, B, C, MOD_DATE, AMT1, AMT2  
      ,RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY A, B, C, AMT1 ORDER BY MOD_DATE DESC) AS rk     
    FROM INPUT_TABLE
```

| A | B | C | MOD_DATE | AMT1 | AMT2 | RK |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | DEF | GHI | 20,221,104 | 2 | 15 | 1 |
| ABC | DEF | GHI | 20,221,104 | 2 | 20 | 1 |
| ABC | DEF | GHI | 20,221,102 | 2 | 10 | 3 |
| ABC | DEF | GHI | 20,221,104 | 4 | 5 | 1 |
| ABC | DEF | GHI | 20,221,104 | 4 | 10 | 1 |
| ABC | DEF | GHI | 20,221,104 | 3 | 10 | 1 |
| ABC | DEF | GHI | 20,221,104 | 3 | 20 | 1 |
| ABC | DEF | GHI | 20,221,102 | 3 | 10 | 3 |
| ABC | DEF | GHI | 20,221,104 | 5 | 5 | 1 |
| ABC | DEF | GHI | 20,221,102 | 5 | 5 | 2 |

we can see there are more 1's than we want, because there are many `A, B, C, AMT1` for the "same" `mod_date`, thus with this data there is no stable last, because in SQL we have "SETS" of rows not rows in any ORDER unless you order them explicitly yourself (they can appear to have an order, but that can and will change).

changing our data to have a `MAGIC_EXTRA_ORDER`:

```
with INPUT_TABLE(MAGIC_EXTRA_ORDER, A, B,C, MOD_DATE, AMT1, AMT2) as (
    select * from values
        (1,'ABC','DEF','GHI',20221102, 2.00, 10.00),
        (2,'ABC','DEF','GHI',20221104, 2.00, 15.00),
        (3,'ABC','DEF','GHI',20221104, 2.00, 20.00),
        (4,'ABC','DEF','GHI',20221102, 3.00, 10.00),
        (5,'ABC','DEF','GHI',20221104, 3.00, 10.00),
        (6,'ABC','DEF','GHI',20221104, 3.00, 20.00),
        (7,'ABC','DEF','GHI',20221104, 4.00, 5.00),
        (8,'ABC','DEF','GHI',20221104, 4.00, 10.00),
        (9,'ABC','DEF','GHI',20221102, 5.00, 5.00),
        (10,'ABC','DEF','GHI',20221104, 5.00, 5.00)
)
```

we can then have stable sorting:

```
SELECT A, B, C, MOD_DATE, AMT1, AMT2  
  ,RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY A, B, C, AMT1 ORDER BY MOD_DATE DESC, MAGIC_EXTRA_ORDER DESC) AS rk     
FROM INPUT_TABLE
```

giving:

| A | B | C | MOD_DATE | AMT1 | AMT2 | RK |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | DEF | GHI | 20,221,104 | 2 | 20 | 1 |
| ABC | DEF | GHI | 20,221,104 | 2 | 15 | 2 |
| ABC | DEF | GHI | 20,221,102 | 2 | 10 | 3 |
| ABC | DEF | GHI | 20,221,104 | 3 | 20 | 1 |
| ABC | DEF | GHI | 20,221,104 | 3 | 10 | 2 |
| ABC | DEF | GHI | 20,221,102 | 3 | 10 | 3 |
| ABC | DEF | GHI | 20,221,104 | 4 | 10 | 1 |
| ABC | DEF | GHI | 20,221,104 | 4 | 5 | 2 |
| ABC | DEF | GHI | 20,221,104 | 5 | 5 | 1 |
| ABC | DEF | GHI | 20,221,102 | 5 | 5 | 2 |

Now your SQL works:

```
SELECT A,B,C, AMT1,AMT2  FROM (
    SELECT A, B, C, MOD_DATE, AMT1, AMT2  
      ,RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY A, B, C, AMT1 ORDER BY MOD_DATE DESC, MAGIC_EXTRA_ORDER DESC) AS rk     
    FROM INPUT_TABLE
) 
WHERE rk = 1;
```

which can be rewritten using a QUALIFY:

```
SELECT A, B, C, MOD_DATE, AMT1, AMT2    
FROM INPUT_TABLE
QUALIFY RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY A, B, C, AMT1 ORDER BY MOD_DATE DESC, MAGIC_EXTRA_ORDER DESC) = 1
```

| A | B | C | MOD_DATE | AMT1 | AMT2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | DEF | GHI | 20,221,104 | 2 | 20 |
| ABC | DEF | GHI | 20,221,104 | 3 | 20 |
| ABC | DEF | GHI | 20,221,104 | 4 | 10 |
| ABC | DEF | GHI | 20,221,104 | 5 | 5 |

Now to the SUM, given the QUALIFY does it's filtering after any GROUPING, we can put s SUM in there:

```
SELECT A, B, C, MOD_DATE, AMT1 
    ,SUM(AMT2) OVER(PARTITION BY A,B,C, AMT1) as AMT2
FROM INPUT_TABLE
QUALIFY RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY A, B, C, AMT1 ORDER BY MOD_DATE DESC, MAGIC_EXTRA_ORDER DESC) = 1
ORDER BY amt1
```

| A | B | C | MOD_DATE | AMT1 | AMT2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | DEF | GHI | 20,221,104 | 2 | 45 |
| ABC | DEF | GHI | 20,221,104 | 3 | 40 |
| ABC | DEF | GHI | 20,221,104 | 4 | 15 |
| ABC | DEF | GHI | 20,221,104 | 5 | 10 |

Note: you have a bug in your example MATHS, ether you want the sum of the other rows, to get you 35, 30 for 2, 3 or you want sum of all rows to get the 15, 10 for 4, 5. But I have leant into the all option as that is what your words also say.